# React Native check the json response from an api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, react-native

In my app I created a login function by retrieving data via the API.

The response I am getting is json and it shows the token when the login succeeded.

How can I check for a valid login? If pw and email are wrong it should refuse to login.

My JSON Response:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "success login",
    "success": "1",
    "id_user": "1",
    "username": "admin",
    "token": "06506e99c55c34fab74db72b8b263014"
}

{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "username atau password salah",
    "success": "0"
}
```

this my code

```
fetch('https://example/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
        body:
          "email=" + this.state.email + "&password=" + this.state.password 
      })
      .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          alert(responseJson);
            // if(responseJson.token){
           this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
          // }else{
          //   alert('gagal');
          // }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
      }).done();
    }
```

here comes my if statement

but when filling in the password and username incorrectly, he can still enter the home page

Comment: Why are you using `response.text()` and there is no check, it just moved to home page without a check

Comment: if i use respose.json ()

my data becomes [object obejct]

Comment: Do you know api specs? what's type of response server is returning? Do you have controll over the response? if yes, change it to json

Comment: It depends on your backend server, try to return a http status code 409 for example from your server if username/password are incorrect..

Comment: I have been invited to respond to my Json

Comment: @MahdiN Nah, for responding to incorrect credential, 401 is the way to go.

Comment: There is no conditional check. You navigate to the home page, so why are you surprised that the user sees the home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this if your login credentials are wrong by using your response:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => { 
                if(responseJson.status == 200){
                   this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
                }
                else if(responseJson.status == 401) {
                    alert("Invalid credentials");
                }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you checked what you are getting in responseJson. Try this response.text() to response.json()

Comment: if i use response.json ()

and I alert (response)

that I get is [object object]

Comment: Dont use alert use console.log